# Flex item with `max-width` and `max-height` causes the text next it to break unnecessarily in Chrome

Tags: css, flexbox

In the snippet below, the `tab__icon` has a `max-width` and a `max-height`, but apparently its causes the text inside of the `tab__label` next to it to break, while there's actually plenty of space.

I know it's the presence of both `max-width` and `max-height` that's causing this problem, because as soon as you change either `max-width` to `width` or `max-height` to `height`, the text no longer breaks, and everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

I also tried adding `flex-shrink: 0;` to `tab__label` but that would cause the text to overflow the parent, which is not what I want.

```css
.tab-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tab-list__item {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.tab__icon {
  max-width: 12px;
  max-height: 12px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-list">
  <div class="tab tab-list__item">
    <svg class="tab__icon" viewBox="0 0 11.25 15"> <g transform="translate(-3)"> <path d="M9.75,7.5A3.75,3.75,0,1,0,6,3.75,3.75,3.75,0,0,0,9.75,7.5Zm0-6.25a2.5,2.5,0,1,1-2.5,2.5A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,9.75,1.25Z" transform="translate(-1.125)"></path> <path d="M8.625,14A5.631,5.631,0,0,0,3,19.625a.625.625,0,1,0,1.25,0,4.375,4.375,0,1,1,8.75,0,.625.625,0,0,0,1.25,0A5.631,5.631,0,0,0,8.625,14Z" transform="translate(0 -5.25)"></path> </g> </svg>
    <span class="tab__label">Some title here</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab tab-list__item">
    <svg class="tab__icon" viewBox="0 0 11.25 15"> <g transform="translate(-3)"> <path d="M9.75,7.5A3.75,3.75,0,1,0,6,3.75,3.75,3.75,0,0,0,9.75,7.5Zm0-6.25a2.5,2.5,0,1,1-2.5,2.5A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,9.75,1.25Z" transform="translate(-1.125)"></path> <path d="M8.625,14A5.631,5.631,0,0,0,3,19.625a.625.625,0,1,0,1.25,0,4.375,4.375,0,1,1,8.75,0,.625.625,0,0,0,1.25,0A5.631,5.631,0,0,0,8.625,14Z" transform="translate(0 -5.25)"></path> </g> </svg>
    <span class="tab__label">Some other title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** As @TemaniAfif pointed out in the comments, this problem only exists in Chrome, Firefox seems to work as expected.

Comment: remove `flex-shrink: 0` from `.tab-list__item` instead give it width of `100%`

Comment: @KunalTanwar Obviously that's not something I'd want to do, since that would cause each of the tabs to take up as much space as possible, that's not what I want, I want them to take up as much space as "needed".

Comment: you can try `flex-shrink: 0` on `.tab__label`

Comment: worth to note that Firefox is giving a different behavior than Chrome

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's right, in Firefox it works as I would expect. But why is that?! Is this a Chrome bug?! And isn't there a way to make this work with `max-width`? I would like to avoid using a fixed `width` in this case if possible.

Comment: I tried the same and my label is not breaking like yours you can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kxe1go6n/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are fixing the width to a max value, you can set any value for width bigger than that. At least, it should make this working on Chrome since it's already fine on Firefox

```css
.tab-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tab-list__item {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.tab__icon {
  max-width: 12px;
  max-height: 12px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-list">
  <div class="tab tab-list__item">
    <svg class="tab__icon" viewBox="0 0 11.25 15"> <g transform="translate(-3)"> <path d="M9.75,7.5A3.75,3.75,0,1,0,6,3.75,3.75,3.75,0,0,0,9.75,7.5Zm0-6.25a2.5,2.5,0,1,1-2.5,2.5A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,9.75,1.25Z" transform="translate(-1.125)"></path> <path d="M8.625,14A5.631,5.631,0,0,0,3,19.625a.625.625,0,1,0,1.25,0,4.375,4.375,0,1,1,8.75,0,.625.625,0,0,0,1.25,0A5.631,5.631,0,0,0,8.625,14Z" transform="translate(0 -5.25)"></path> </g> </svg>
    <span class="tab__label">Some title here</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab tab-list__item">
    <svg class="tab__icon" viewBox="0 0 11.25 15"> <g transform="translate(-3)"> <path d="M9.75,7.5A3.75,3.75,0,1,0,6,3.75,3.75,3.75,0,0,0,9.75,7.5Zm0-6.25a2.5,2.5,0,1,1-2.5,2.5A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,9.75,1.25Z" transform="translate(-1.125)"></path> <path d="M8.625,14A5.631,5.631,0,0,0,3,19.625a.625.625,0,1,0,1.25,0,4.375,4.375,0,1,1,8.75,0,.625.625,0,0,0,1.25,0A5.631,5.631,0,0,0,8.625,14Z" transform="translate(0 -5.25)"></path> </g> </svg>
    <span class="tab__label">Some other title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: he mentioned to avoid fixed width

Comment: @KunalTanwar Here that fixed width is not an actual fixed width. It's just there to fix this problem.

Comment: @KunalTanwar it's an arbitrary big value. It's not *fixed* and it can be any big value

Comment: This is interesting, thank you. I'm curious as to why this problem even exists in the first place, do you have any idea? Why would Chrome not work as expected just with the max-width and max-height alone?

Comment: @Arad it's for sure related to the intrinsic value of the SVG. A bit tricky to explain but to use easy words: Chrome is considering the SVG having width:0 to find the width of the container and later he increase the width of SVG (without changing the one of the container) which will make the text to wrap

Comment: @TemaniAfif Aha, that makes sense. Thanks. But which one do you think is behaving incorrectly here, Firefox or Chrome? Because as you mentioned Firefox behaves differently. So, I guess one of them has to be wrong. Can't this be considered a bug in Chrome, for example?

Comment: @Arad I would say Firefox is correct but Chrome is not 100% incorrect. It's not the first time I face such behavior especially when SVG is involved. There are a lot of tricky behaviors of flexbox that aren't very well defined so we can easily face such situation. You can always raise a chrome bug. The behavior is non-intuitive and unexpected so it can fall under the bug umbrella.

Answer (score 0):

### Mine is working just fine.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container .tab {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">
    <span>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M12 2a5 5 0 1 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 0-5-5zm0 8a3 3 0 1 1 3-3 3 3 0 0 1-3 3zm9 11v-1a7 7 0 0 0-7-7h-4a7 7 0 0 0-7 7v1h2v-1a5 5 0 0 1 5-5h4a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v1z"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <label>Some title here</label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <span>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path d="M12 2a5 5 0 1 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 0-5-5zm0 8a3 3 0 1 1 3-3 3 3 0 0 1-3 3zm9 11v-1a7 7 0 0 0-7-7h-4a7 7 0 0 0-7 7v1h2v-1a5 5 0 0 1 5-5h4a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v1z"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <label>Some other title</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, you are also using fixed width ... your comment apply to you.

Comment: You're giving the SVG tag a width and height here, so it's essentially the same as giving it a `width: 24px` in CSS. But thank you for your efforts, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Arad why you don't want to give fixed width to `svg's`